# NamedNativeQuery throwing Invalid Column Name Exception on Entity with FK

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, exception

I working on a simple code to map one entity with a foreign key into a list to display results, using @NamedNativeQuery but still getting "java.sql.SQLException: Nombre de columna no válido" (Invalid column name) when calling that query.list

Tables

```
TABLE "schema"."BEDE_ESTADOS" 

"CODIGO_ESTADO" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DESCRIPCION" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"HABILITADO" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "PK_BEDE_ESTADOS" PRIMARY KEY ("CODIGO_ESTADO")

TABLE "schema"."BEDE_CATEGORIA_HORA" 
"CODIGO_CATEGORIA" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DESCRIPCION" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"CODIGO_ESTADO" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"TOPE_HORAS" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"OBJETO_GASTO" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
CONSTRAINT "PK_BEDE_CATEGORIA_HORA" PRIMARY KEY ("CODIGO_CATEGORIA"),
CONSTRAINT "FK_BEDE_CATEG_HORA_BEDE_ESTADO" FOREIGN KEY ("CODIGO_ESTADO")
  REFERENCES "schema"."BEDE_ESTADOS" ("CODIGO_ESTADO")
```

Entities

```
    public class BedeEstados implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "codigo_Sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "codigo_Sequence", 
        sequenceName = "schema.SEQ_BEDE_ESTADOS_CODIGO_ESTADO",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "CODIGO_ESTADO")
private Short codigoEstado;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
private String descripcion;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "HABILITADO")
private short habilitado;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION")
private String usuarioUltimaModificacion;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaUltimaModificacion;

public BedeEstados() {
}
```

Get/Set....................
}

```
public class BedeCategoriaHora implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "codigo_SequenceCategoriaHora")
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "codigo_SequenceCategoriaHora", 
        sequenceName = "SAE_DESIGNACIONES_WEB.SEQ_BEDE_CATEGORIA_HORA_COD_CT",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "CODIGO_CATEGORIA")
private Short codigoCategoria;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
private String descripcion;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TOPE_HORAS")
private short topeHoras;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "OBJETO_GASTO")
private String objetoGasto;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION")
private String usuarioUltimaModificacion;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fechaUltimaModificacion;
@JoinColumn(name = "CODIGO_ESTADO", referencedColumnName = "CODIGO_ESTADO")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private BedeEstados codigoEstado;
```

Get/Set.............
}

@NamedNativeQuery

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "BedeCategoriaHora.obtenerCategorias",
        query ="SELECT  * FROM "
                + "(SELECT  q.*, rownum rn FROM "
                    + "(SELECT  ct.*, e.CODIGO_ESTADO AS COD_ESTADO, E.DESCRIPCION AS DESC_ESTADO "
                    + " FROM schema.BEDE_CATEGORIA_HORA ct, schema.BEDE_ESTADOS e"
                    + " WHERE ct.CODIGO_ESTADO = e.CODIGO_ESTADO"
                    + " AND ct.CODIGO_CATEGORIA LIKE :pFiltroIdRegistro"
                    + " AND UPPER(ct.DESCRIPCION) LIKE :pFiltroDescripcion "
                    + "ORDER BY ct.CODIGO_CATEGORIA)"
                + " q)  "
               + "WHERE rn BETWEEN :pPrimerRegistro AND :pUltimoRegistro",
        resultSetMapping = "obtenerCategoriasEntidad")
```

@SqlResultSetMapping

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "obtenerCategoriasEntidad",
        entities = {
            @EntityResult(entityClass = BedeCategoriaHora.class,
                    fields = {
                    @FieldResult(name = "CODIGO_CATEGORIA", column = "CODIGO_CATEGORIA"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "DESCRIPCION", column = "DESC_ESTADO"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "CODIGO_ESTADO", column = "CODIGO_ESTADO"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "TOPE_HORAS", column = "TOPE_HORAS"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "OBJETO_GASTO", column = "OBJETO_GASTO"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION", column = "USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION", column = "FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION"),
                    }
            ),
            @EntityResult(entityClass = BedeEstados.class,
                    fields = {
                    @FieldResult(name = "CODIGO_ESTADO", column = "COD_ESTADO"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "DESCRIPCION", column = "DESC_ESTADO"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "HABILITADO", column = "HABILITADO"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION", column = "USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION", column = "FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION"),
                    }
            )
        },
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "rn")
        })
```

Call

```
List <Object[]> results;

     results = this.dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("BedeCategoriaHora.obtenerCategorias")
            .setParameter(lNombresParametros[0], lValoresParametros[0])
            .setParameter(lNombresParametros[1], lValoresParametros[1])
            .setParameter(lNombresParametros[2], lValoresParametros[2])
            .setParameter(lNombresParametros[3], lValoresParametros[3])
            .list();
```

Error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Nombre de columna no válido
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3677)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2749)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getShort(OracleResultSet.java:482)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.getShort(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.SmallIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(SmallIntTypeDescriptor.java:61)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
at cr.ac.ucr.desgweb.dao.BedeCategoriaHora_Dao.listarRegistros(BedeCategoriaHora_Dao.java:99)
at cr.ac.ucr.desgweb.dao.BedeCategoriaHora_Dao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$850413d6.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at cr.ac.ucr.desgweb.dao.BedeCategoriaHora_Dao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e7819990.listarRegistros(<generated>)
at cr.ac.ucr.desgweb.modelo.BedeCategoriaHoraMgr.listarRegistros(BedeCategoriaHoraMgr.java:37)
at cr.ac.ucr.desgweb.vista.VistaBedeCategoriaHora.listarRegistros(VistaBedeCategoriaHora.java:288)
at cr.ac.ucr.desgweb.vista.VistaBedeCategoriaHora.inicializar(VistaBedeCategoriaHora.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:397)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1438)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:459)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:332)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:43)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
at org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver.resolveSpringBean(DelegatingVariableResolver.java:139)
at org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver.resolveVariable(DelegatingVariableResolver.java:112)
at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverChainWrapper.getValue(VariableResolverChainWrapper.java:107)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:184)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.BaseInputRenderer.getValue(BaseInputRenderer.java:36)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:43)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:370)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:365)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:96)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:492)
at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
at com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DFaceletViewHandler.java:282)
at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:159)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:19)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

debug

```
15:39:43,356  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:233 - SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: 99999
15:39:43,356 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:234 - Nombre de columna no válido
15:39:43,363 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:182 - rollback
15:39:43,364 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:223 - re-enabling autocommit
15:39:43,364 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:193 - rolled back JDBC Connection
```

Comment: It's doubtful that the problem has anything to do with the FK constraint.  More likely you have misspelled a column name somewhere, or asked for one that is not actually returned among your results.  Taking an educated guess based on the stack trace, I'd look first at your result set mapping.  I don't have time at the moment to actually do that myself.

Comment: Thank´s for the answer. Actually the title include FK to let you know there is two tables related. I will try to simplify things starting with set mapping.